# SDB command not found

Tags: root, tizen, tizen-sdb

I have two PCs, ones that runs mac & the other ubuntu, I installed tizen sdk on both and it is working fine, however, as I'm trying to pull files from the tizen device I get an error message "SDB connection error", which means that my device is not rooted, so when I try to root it using sdb command on both mac & ubuntu I get that sdb command not found, even though I did navigate into the folder in which sdb exist, tizen-sdk/tools and execute the command, but still got the same massage.
what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What if you run `./sdb` in the tools directory?

Comment: I did, it shows me thisSmart Development Bridge version 2.2.29

 Usage : sdb [option] <command> [parameters]

 options:
  -e, --emulator                - direct command to the only running emulator
                                  return an error if more than one emulator is running
  -d, --device                  - direct command to the only connected USB device
 ... and the list of sdb commands

Comment: What device are you talking about, Gear 2/S or emulator?

Answer (score 2):

Use the below step to get solved.

Step 1: open terminal

Step 2: write command `$ nano ~/.bash_profile`

Step 3: Paste the given below the code line to the bottom of and change <pc_user_name> to your PC name, then save it and exit.

```
export TIZEN_HOME=/Users/<pc_user_name>/tizen-studio
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/<pc_user_name>/tizen-studio/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/<pc_user_name>/tizen-studio/tools/ide/bin
```

Step 4: write command `$ source ~/.bash_profile`

Step 5: `$ sdb` write command to sdb instruction

Either you can be going this path to find `./sdb` and other write sdb command will work perfectly.

> path: /Users/<pc_user_name>/tizen-studio/tools/sdb

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can try to fix this.

1. Use the Connection explorer in SDK
   The SDK provides a "Connection Explorer" view on the bottom left corner.
   It provides an icon for pulling files from the device.
2. Your PATH variable might not be set properly.
   On Ubuntu you can verify this using "export" and checking if your PATH variable points to /tizen-sdk/tools
   (Note : This should be set typically during the SDK installation.)
   Check your "command shell rc file (.bashrc) or your .profile files to check if PATH variable is being overridden.

One of these two should help you.
Let me know how it goes.

Comment: 1- I tried this as I said, but I still get the error "SDB connection error" & I searched the internet & the reason for this error was because the device isnt rooted & I want to use the sdb command to root it but it didnt work. 2- I'm a newbie in ubuntu so if you could please guide me on how to check this? thank you

Comment: Open bash using "Ctrl + Alt + T", type the following command - export PATH=$HOME/tizen-sdk/tools:$PATH <enter>, type sdb. (or) from bash prompt : $HOME/tizen-sdk/tools/sdb. It would be helpful if you paste the output of the command "export" from bash.

Comment: I get this as well Smart Development Bridge version 2.2.29 Usage : sdb [option] <command> [parameters] options: -e, --emulator - direct command to the only running emulator return an error if more than one emulator is running -d, --device - direct command to the only connected USB device ... and the list of sdb commands

Comment: There you have it. You are running sdb. Now you can use one of the options - sdb pull <remote file> <local file>

Comment: Did it fix your problem?

Comment: im in the tools dir and I get: ➜  tools sdb
zsh: command not found: sdb

Answer (score 0):

You have to export the Tizen path to the PATH variable
In your Ubuntu OS,

1. Open Home directory
2. Press CTRL+H
3. Open .bashrc file
4. Append the text at last of the file
   export PATH=$PATH:/home/YOUR_PC_NAME/tizen-sdk/tools

Try now.